# Django - Using forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a multi-select list of checkboxes for names in a database.

I thought I could do the below in the from, and do some kind of loop in the template to render each name, but noting I try works. Is this the correct approach, any clues on how to render this in the template?

Thanks

```
from django import forms
from .models import Player

class PlayerForm(forms.Form):

    team = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        choices=[Player.objects.all()]
    )


from django.db import models

class Player(models.Model):
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Last Name')
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='First Name')
    wins = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    loss = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.lname)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['lname']
```

Comment: Can you try with `choices=Player.objects.all()`? (removing the outer list). I suspect it could cause some issues since it basically wrap the list of results in another list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely. If you need to select a option among model options, you should use a [**`ModelMultipleChoiceField`**  field [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField). This will not only make it more convenient to work with data, but it will furthermore each time query the database, such that, if you add a new `Player`, one can select that one.

You thus can implement this as:

```
class TeamForm(forms.Form):
    team = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        queryset=Player.objects.all()
    )
```

It might furthermore be better to name your form `TeamForm`, since you here do not create/update/... a `Player`, but you select a team.

Comment: That didi it! Thanks, I'm putting you in the will :-)